# How do i toggle between classes of an element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a script that sets a class for the label of a checkbox when i click it once and when i click it again it reverts to the first class.

This is the code i have:

```
    <label for="img1">
    <img class="img1" src="Images/testimg.jpg" onclick="javascript:test()" id="t1" />
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="img1" name="img1" value="1" />
```

I want the test function to assign the class img2 when it is called and when i call it again to assign the class img1.

Comment: Do you need to replace current classes (a trivial task) or add a new one (not difficult, but requires a helper function)?

Comment: For your entertainment, a Stack Overflow classic: [Not enough jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/141539).

Comment: Perhaps you can use this:
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.toggle('MyClass');

Answer (score 4):

**JavaScript**

```
function toggleClass(element, origin, target) {
    var newClass = element.className.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0, i < newClass.length; i++) {
        if (origin.localeCompare(newClass[i]) == 0) {
            newClass[i] = target;
        };
    };
    element.className = newClass.join(" ");
};
// Usage
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
toggleClass(img, "img1 img2");
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#img1").toggleClass("img1 img2");
```

More [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: he said javascript, not jquery

Comment: Don't you mean `.toggleClass("img1 img2");`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Good catch.. @alex23: update your question accordingly: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className  `One or more class names (separated by spaces)...`

Answer (score 2):

```
function test() {
    t1.className = t1.className == 'img1' ? 'img2' : 'img1';
}
```

Related: [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: This is ok I suppose, `t1.className = t1.className == t1.className.indexOf('img1') > -1 ? t1.className.replace('img1','img2') : t1.className.replace('img2','img1')';`

Comment: that also won't work.  if you had 'img10' as a classname then you'd end up with 'img20' after the swap, which isn't what you want.

Comment: I would say _duplicate_ rather than _related_.

Comment: @alex23, unless specified differently, assumed single classed dom element. I'm personnally pulling the chariot because I want to, not only because of the carrot.

Comment: @XaviLópez, right, depends on your morning mood :D

Comment: `t1.className = /(^|\s)img1($|\s)/g.test(t1.className) ? t1.className.replace(/(^|\s)img1($|\s)/g, 'img2') : t1.className.replace(/(^|\s)img2($|\s)/g, 'img1');` This is working fine :). Need optimization though. and even I think it is not good to go with regex here, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jQuery I will suggest you 2 things:

1. With `onclick` property, you don't need to set `javascript:` before calling a function. It will not work if you use it.
2. You can send the element through the function like this: `onclick=test(this)`. Now you will only have to compare his class.

```
function testFunction(element) {
    if (element.className === 'img1') {
        element.className = 'img2';
    } else {
        element.className = 'img1';
    }
}
```

**TAKE CARE** if you use multiclasses, because you will need to add them into the classname. This function will remove full class name for the new one.

Answer (score -1):

You could use JQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method:

```
function toggler() {
    $('#t1').toggleClass('img2 img1')

}
```

Comment: downvoters should consult http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question/48195#48195